# Can't identify my plant

Tags: identification, seedlings

I planted a seed 2-3 weeks ago from a fruit (or possibly a vegetable) and now I have completely forgot what it was. Unfortunately I did not put a note on the pot. What could it be? My first guess was orange plant/tree, but they don't look like that do they?

[image]

[image]

It would be great to identify my seedling with the help of you guys.

Answer (score 4):

This is a seedling from the [Cucurbitaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbitaceae) family, probably the genus [Cucurbita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita). In other words, pumpkin, squash, zucchini, maybe melon or cucumber.

It was definitely a plant with fully developed seeds in the ripe fruit, so probably not a zucchini or cucumber, as they are typically sold with un- or underdeveloped seeds. If they are from a home harvest, this may be different, of course.

This should be enough to trigger your memory of what you stuck in the pot?

Comment: Ah yes! Pumpkin it is. I remember now. I opened up a pumpkin to make a soup and there was a seed that had started to germinate inside the pumpkin already so I planted it in a pot. Thank you so much for identifying it for me!

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gBGt5OeAQFk  this vid applies to this plant.  as it grows you will notice it is aware of its surroundings. It reaches out to grab things with its tendrils and even lifts itself up as though its doing pushups if the floor is too hot!  Have a look its worth it https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MPql1VHbYl4